# dynamic array size within struct without another member indicate the size

Tags: c, design-patterns

I have a struct defined as:

```
struct Voxel1
{
   float array[16];
};
```

where later I can allocate an image as a continuous memory of a specified number of Voxels, e.g.,

```
int voxelNum = 1000;
Voxel1* image = (Voxel1*)calloc(voxelNum, sizeof(Voxel1));
```

then I can access continuous memory of `sizeof(Voxel1)` to do some operation, e.g.,

```
Voxel1 a;
//do some computation on a, 
//copy it to the 101-th voxel in the image
image[100] = a;
```

My problem is that later I decide the size of array is decided at run-time, i.e., the array member in Voxel1 is of dynamic size. Is there a way that I can do it? My requirement is that I don't want to save an additional member to indicate the size of the array, like the one below:

```
struct Voxel2
{
   size_t size;
   float* array;
}IDontWantThisDefinition;
```

Due to this additional member, later my actual voxel2 size will be `sizeof(float)*size+sizeof(size_t)` , now when I try to modify voxel values, they are not as continuous as before.

What I desire is some definition (I know Voxel3 is invalid) has the following definition except `size` can be decided at run-time:

```
struct Voxel3
{
   //so I want size to be static so that it does not take memory on the stack
   //also I want it to be const so that it can be used to define array's size
   static const size_t size;
   float array[size];
}DesireButInvalidDefinition;
```

where in a program I can do something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int arraysize = 32;
    //allocate 1000 voxels where each voxel has 32 float element
    Voxel3* image = (Voxel3*)calloc(1000, sizeof(Voxel3));
    Voxel3 anotherVoxel;
    image[100]=anotherVoxel;
}
```

I am not sure if there is any solution to satisfy such design, or what design can do something close to what I want. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using `c` or `c++`? In your use case, it can make a difference. For `c`, `Voxel2` looks like the best bet. Make `size` a global/static, defined _outside_ of the struct

Comment: I will remove the C++ tag, since it seems you're coding in C anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say what is the best approach, but as I mentioned in my top comment, move the size outside of the struct definition.

First you have to calculate the dynamic size before doing anything.

```
int voxel_size;                         // dynamically computed

typedef struct _Voxel {
    float *array;                       // count is voxel_size
} Voxel;

typedef struct _VoxelArray {
    int count;
    Voxel *voxels;
} VoxelArray;

void
voxel_init(Voxel *vox)
{

    vox->array = calloc(voxel_size,sizeof(float));
}

Voxel *
voxel_alloc(int count)
{
    Voxel *vox;

    vox = calloc(count,sizeof(voxel));

    for (int idx = 0;  idx < count;  ++idx)
        voxel_init(vox + idx);

    return vox;
}

VoxelArray *
voxel_array(VoxelArray *arr,int count)
{

    if (arr == NULL)
        arr = calloc(1,sizeof(VoxelArray));

    arr->count = count;
    arr->voxels = voxel_alloc(count);

    return arr;
}

int
main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    voxel_size = 32;

    Voxel anotherVoxel;
    voxel_init(&anotherVoxel);

    //allocate 1000 voxels where each voxel has 32 float element
    Voxel *image = voxel_alloc(1000);
    image[100] = anotherVoxel;

    VoxelArray varray;
    voxel_array(&varray,1000);
    varray.voxels[100] = anotherVoxel;

    VoxelArray *varrptr = voxel_array(NULL,1000);
    varrptr->voxels[100] = anotherVoxel;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

By separating data and data accessor, this is what I got. Not a good example of memory management, though.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdlib>

// Both Voxel3 and Voxel3Image are just data accessors,
// which provide a way to access the real data.

struct Voxel3
{
    static size_t size;
    float *array;
    Voxel3(float *data = nullptr) {
        array = data;
    }
    // 'image[100]=anotherVoxel;' won't do the right
    // thing(deep copy) without this.
    Voxel3 & operator = (const Voxel3 &v) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            array[i] = v.array[i];
        return *this;
    }
};

size_t Voxel3::size;

// you want image[100], use this.
struct Voxel3Image
{
    float *data_ref;
    Voxel3Image(float *data = nullptr) {
        data_ref = data;
    }
    // image[100] need this.
    Voxel3 operator [] (int i) {
        return Voxel3(data_ref + i * Voxel3::size);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Voxel3::size = 32;

    float *real_data = (float*)calloc(1000,
                                      sizeof(float) * Voxel3::size);
                                      // sizeof(Voxel3) == sizeof(float *),
                                      // not what your want.

    // allocate 1000 voxels where each voxel has 32 float element
    Voxel3Image image( real_data );
    Voxel3 anotherVoxel;
    // initialize anotherVoxel
    image[100]=anotherVoxel;
    return 0;
}
```